# ILNumerics Drawing a surface having (x,y,z) coordinates

Tags: graph, 3d, ilnumerics, geometry-surface

I am really new in programming with C#. I have an Array of points in the following form

//An Array containing point coordinates:

double[,] graphData=new double[100,3];
//Each element of graph data contain coordinate of a point:

graphData[1;:]=(x1,y1,z1);

I wanna draw a surface using ILNumerics. I couldn't find any example for this case. Would you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

The link posted in the accepted answer points to an outdated part of the ILNumerics documentation which is obsolete now. Up from version 3, surfaces utilize a new scene graph based rendering API.

Documentation: http://ilnumerics.net/surface-plots.html

However, the linke posted by Roy Dictus may help in explaining how to turn your data into matrix shaped data, suitable for surface rendering.

Basically, surfaces create a mesh based on the *matrix* shaped input data. It connects the incoming points according to their location in the input matrix. So instead of a list of points you have to provide:

- a single matrix of Z values, if a regular grid of heights values is to be rendered only, or
- same shaped matrices for Z, X and Y values for non-regular grids and parametric surfaces.

Comment: I have a parametric surface. So I need to great one matrix for each coordinate? Could you Please provide some code?

Comment: Its one big 3D array (m x n x 3). Every coordinate (Z,X and Y) corresponds to one slice (m x n) in the array. If your points are organized as a grid, you may simply try to reshape your data. At the end, they must look like the graphic found on the docu: http://ilnumerics.net/surface-plots.html

Answer (score 1):

How to plot a 3D Surface using ILNumerics: http://ilnumerics.net/forum/index.php?p=/discussion/163/how-to-plot-a-3d-surface-/p1

Comment: This link is actually outdated. You may want to try the new version, which works differently. See my answer.